# Why is this ALL CAPS post NOT rude

Tags: discussion

I flagged the following post in the triage as rude:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849752/display-the-sql-server-messages-as-they-appear

I think a all caps post violates the first rule of the Be nice page:

> **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.**
>
> Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.

Since we usually don't scream to each other, but talk nicely instead.

Comment: Because that can trivially be corrected without changing the meaning of the post. There are far better reasons to close that post – it has been closed as "too broad" by now (and also deleted).

Comment: Regardless, judging by the fact that they always wrote "i" in a lower case, I would guess they weren't even aware they wrote it all caps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All caps posts may not be nice but their *intent* is not to be insulting which is what a rude post aims to be.

Rude posts are those that aim to cause harm or distress to its intended target.