# Is Capitalizing sentences considered rude?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on SO

[newline characters are not preserved on server side from h:inputTextarea using jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919163/newline-characters-are-not-preserved-on-server-side-from-hinputtextarea-using-j)

In which the last line was originally capitalised

> HOW DO I GET NEWLINES TO TRANSFER TO THE BACKING PROPERTY ???

I since edited the question because I had a very experienced SO (with 5700 rep) user tell me to de-capitalise the line because capitalisation **always** means you are shouting, which I assume he considered rude, inaproppriate or offensive.
Shortly after this comment I received a down vote on my question....

My question was in no way irrelevant, not useful or unclear and I was left feeling very disappointed that my reputation had been tarnished. I'm still new to SO so I'd like to know what people think about this.

The only reason I capitalised the line in the first place was because I was trying to show the **frustration** that the problem was causing me. I in no way meant to be rude, I feel that it would be a real stretch of the imagination for someone to consider it as such.

I'm inclined to agree with the answer given on this similar meta post:

[Why is this ALL CAPS post NOT rude](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314937/why-is-this-all-caps-post-not-rude)

does capitalisation in a question have no place on SO ?? was I in the wrong ??

Comment: WHY WOULD YOU SHOUT IF YOU CAN USE **BOLD** OR *ITALICS* TO MAKE YOUR QUESTION STAND OUT ????????????????????

Comment: Relevant stackexchange post https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122760/347191

Comment: On a more serious note: The questions here and their answers are meant for future visitors to be helpful as well. Don't bother them with your frustration. Your emotions have no place in posts here. Nor does frivolous styling.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll make a point to be more careful in the future

Comment: With out talking about Gutenberg, and typographic studies about legibility and readability. Caps is a way to add loudness, and it add a lot of it. I can't remember a time where all caps were not 'text-shouting'. But yes capitalised sentense is rude. And as a non english speaker, it's annoying as hell. it adds to mutch noise. The only thing worst than a fully capitalised post is .. an all caps question with repetitive punctuation and world that do not exist like textual representation of emoji.

Comment: @rene don't forget about emoji characters like ‍‍‍

Comment: @gnat I can hardly wait for the Glorious Twelvth so I can hunt emoji again. I have clened my gun and arranged for beaters.

Comment: I would not flag all-caps as rude, but it is 'grating'.  I class it in the same set as 'Urgent', 'ASAP' or 'Emergency', and I typically downvote and move on to the next question without reading further.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's visually jarring and not germane to your question.  It doesn't make sense to have that specific sentence in caps, and diligent editors would and should be removing that sort of thing.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll make a point to be more careful in the future

Comment: @JerryB.no.1intern If you want to make a sentence or point stand out, **Make it bold**